# Immigration to Australia with 2 wives

Tags: australia, marriage, pakistani-citizen

I am a Muslim and I have two wives in Pakistan. I want to apply for Australian immigration. I want to apply with my second wife and the children from my first wife. Is there a problem with doing that or must I include my first wife on the application? Are there any chances of being able to bring my first wife too?

Comment: There's a duplicate of this on [travel.se], https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105669/can-having-a-second-wife-affect-my-australian-visa-processing-stay

Comment: @mkennedy Not a dupe, since there are children involved.

Comment: Which wife are you legally married to? It might be difficult to bring a 'wife' that is not legally married to you when you are legally married to another.

Answer (score 4):

When immigrating to Australia, you can bring **one (1) partner** and **all underage children for which you are the legal guardian**.  So if your children with your first wife are under 18, and she consents to bringing them to Australia (this will need to be in writing and certified), you should be fine, even if your first wife does not join you.

However, Australia does not recognize multiple marriage, so you can only bring your first or second wife, not both.

See also: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105669/can-having-a-second-wife-affect-my-australian-visa-processing-stay